# Are Father, Son, and Holy Spirit explicitly identified as "persons" in any writings directly associated with the Nicene Creed?

Tags: trinity, church-history, nicene-creed, persons-of-the-trinity

Neither version of the [Nicene Creed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed) (325 or 381) contains the word "person," in the singular or in the plural.

Are there any extant writings that came out of, or are closely associated with, either the [First Council of Nicaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea) in 325 AD or the [First Council of Constantinople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Constantinople) in 381 AD that explicitly state that the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are "persons," or that each of them individually is a "person"?

Later theologians view the Nicene Creed as affirming that the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are *persons* of God. However, the creed itself does not actually *state* that they are persons.

Is there any documentary evidence from the time that the creed was formulated in 325 AD, or from the time that it was revised in 381 AD, that the writers of the creed meant it to be read as saying that Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are each individually *persons* of God?

I am especially looking for *explicit* language to that effect rather than language that could merely be *interpreted* to mean that their intent was to affirm that Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are "persons."

As a contrast and an example of what I am looking for, the [Athanasian Creed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasian_Creed) explicitly identifies Father, Son, and Holy Spirit as *persons* of God:

> And the catholic faith is this: That we worship one God in Trinity, and Trinity in Unity; Neither confounding the *Persons;* nor dividing the Essence. For there is one *Person* of the Father; another of the Son; and another of the Holy Ghost. *(italics added)*

The origin and authorship of the Athanasian Creed are disputed, but it was almost certainly composed centuries after the Nicene Creed.

Comment: Would statements that they have, or are, "personalities" be sufficiently explicit?

Comment: @MattGutting Probably. I'd have to see them. The statements would be in Greek, or perhaps in Latin, so it would depend on the meaning of the words in the original language.

Comment: As a footnote, I was nudged to finally ask this question by another recent question: [Do we know of any case of the concept of the Holy Spirit being a person existing among Christians before the Constantinople council of 381 A.D.?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/41917/do-we-know-of-any-case-of-the-concept-of-the-holy-spirit-being-a-person-existing)

Comment: I'd imagine Greek, if we're going back that far.

Comment: Speaking of which....it’s not clear to me what “explicit” word you would like to see representing this in the (Greek) Nicene Creed or derivatives. In Biblical Greek, the word we translate “person” is generally ἄνθρωπος, “man”. Yet this term in English we reserve for a single 1/3 of the Godhead for 30-some-odd years. The concept of “personhood” as it describes a [legal standing in Western civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_personality) (I think the derivation of the sort of personhood you’re referencing) does not have an obvious (to me) Greek correlate.

Comment: My point being only that.... the absence of this terminology may have more to do with the language in which it was written and the historical development of the concept of “personhood" (primarily in Latin) than it does with a post-Nicene change in the understanding of the nature of the trinity. But that would be out of my league!

Comment: @Susan Then we get into the whole *ousia* / *hypostasis* / *substantia* sort of thing ...

Comment: See also (I’m sure those here already have; I hadn’t): [When in the development of trinitarian doctrine was the word “persons” first applied to God?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/39816/13677) I gather y’all have been at this for a while....

Comment: @Susan I've been pushing the "person" thing for a while. For the purposes of my own (Swedenborgian) theology, I'm attempting to pinpoint where and when the doctrine of the Trinity of persons originated. Swedenborg traces it to the First Council of Nicaea. But that creed doesn't actually contain the word "person." Tertullian, an earlier Latin theologian, does use the word "person" in reference to the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. Perhaps the language issue does have a bearing on it.

Comment: @Susan However, if there effectively is no word in Greek equivalent to the Latin word *persona,* that would imply to me that the doctrine of the trinity of persons was absent from *all* of the Greek writings (including, of course, the New Testament), and developed only among Latin theologians. It would seem odd, though, that Greek wouldn't have an equivalent word. My Greek is not good enough to make that evaluation.

Comment: Mine is certainly not the be-all and end-all of Greek vocabulary either, and it is notably limited to the LXX-NT era, i.e. a bit earlier than what you’re asking about here. In addition to the language issues, though, these “show-me-the-word” quests always feel a bit anachronistic to me.

Comment: @Susan Why "anachronistic"? I generally think that words reflect concepts, and that if there is a concept in people's minds, they'll adopt, adapt, or coin a word to express it. I do not believe that the "persons of God" concept was in people's minds in the first couple centuries of the Christian era, and developed only after that, probably starting with Tertullian. The absence of a word meaning "persons" in that sense would indicate to me a lack of the concept in people's minds.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to continue this in chat?

Comment: @MattGutting *Hypostasis* seems to be the Greek equivalent of the Latin *persona.* But I hear that there are some complications along the way, with *ousia* and *hypostasis* apparently swapping meanings, or some such thing, along the way. The Wikipedia page on [Tertullian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertullian) states that Tertullian's Latin *"tres personae, una substantia"* formula derives from the Greek *"treis hypostases, homoousios."*

Comment: @MattGutting The Wikipedia page on [Hypostasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostasis_(philosophy_and_religion)) seems to suggest that it had meaning not identical with the Latin *persona* prior to the [Cappadocian Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappadocian_Fathers) in the fourth century.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. I have been able to find two letters, one related to the calling of the Council of Nicea and the other related to the judgment of the Council of Constantinople, where the word "persons" is used to describe the relations within the Godhead.

## Council of Nicea (325)

First, some background. [Alexander of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Alexander_I_of_Alexandria)'s conflict with Arius was the impetus for the council, as described by [Khaled Anatolios](http://theology.nd.edu/people/faculty/khaled-anatolios/) in *[Retrieving Nicaea](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/080103132X)* (page 42):

> Arius and Alexander could not reconcile their differences over how to conceive the relation between the Father and the Son, however, and Arius was excommunicated from the Egyptian church sometime in the early 320s. Both Arius and Alexander appealed to surrounding bishops for support, and in response to the expanding controversy, the emperor Constantine convened the Council of Nicaea in 325.

[One of Alexander's appeals mentioned above, a 324  letter](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0622.htm) to fellow bishop [Alexander of Constantinople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_of_Constantinople) explicitly affirmed the personhood of the Son and implied the personhood of the Father:

> But that the Son of God was not made "from things which are not," and that there was no "time when He was not," the evangelist John sufficiently shows, when he thus writes concerning Him: "The only-begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father." [John 1:18] For since that divine teacher intended to show that the Father and the Son are two things inseparable the one from the other, he spoke of Him as being in the bosom of the Father. Now that also the Word of God is not comprehended in the number of things that were created "from things which are not," the same John says, "All things were made by Him." For he set forth His proper personality [[another translation](http://web.archive.org/web/20150701110712/http://www.fourthcentury.com/index.php/urkunde-14) says, "He also shows that **he is a unique person**"], saying, "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. All things were made by Him; and without Him was not anything made that was made." [John 1:1-3]

Later in the same letter, he appears to affirm the personhood of both:

> "I and My Father are one," [John 10:30] which indeed the Lord says, not as proclaiming Himself to be the Father, nor to demonstrate that **two persons** are one; but that the Son of the Father most exactly preserves the expressed likeness of the Father.

Later still, he strongly implies the personhood of the Spirit:

> Besides the pious opinion concerning the Father and the Son, we confess to one **Holy Spirit, as the divine Scriptures teach us; who** has inaugurated both the holy men of the Old Testament, and the divine teachers of that which is called the New.

## Council of Constantinople (381)

A [letter written by the bishops gathered at Constantinople](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Councils/ecum02.htm) uses the term "persons" and affirms its consistency with the original Nicene Creed:

> What we have undergone -- persecutions, afflictions, imperial threats, cruelty from officials, and whatever other trial at the hands of heretics -- we have put up with for the sake of the gospel faith established by the 318 fathers at Nicaea in Bithynia. You, we and all who are not bent on subverting the word of the true faith should give this creed our approval. It is the most ancient and is consistent with our baptism. It tells us how to believe in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the holy Spirit: believing also, of course, that **the Father, the Son and the holy Spirit have a single Godhead and power and substance, a dignity deserving the same honour and a co-eternal sovereignty, in three most perfect hypostases, or three perfect persons**. So there is no place for Sabellius's diseased theory in which the hypostases are confused and thus their proper characteristics destroyed. Nor may the blasphemy of Eunomians and Arians and Pneumatomachi prevail.

<sub>The above translation of the bishops' letter is originally from *[Decrees of the Ecumenical Councils](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0878404902)* by Norman Tanner. [Read the relevant pages](http://faculty.cua.edu/pennington/Canon%20Law/Councils/Constantinople%20381.pdf) for yourself (hat-tip to [Susan](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/13677/susan)), which include the original Greek along with a Latin translation.</sub>

## Terminology

In the letters quoted above, the word "person" is a translation of the Greek *[prosopon](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=92990)*. R.P.C. Hanson explains in *[The Search for the Christian Doctrine of God](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/056703092X)* (pg. 183) that "for at least the first half of the period 318-381," which includes the time of the first council, "and in some cases considerably later, *ousia* and *hypostasis* are used as virtual synonyms." This led to Nicea's anathematization of those who say that the Father and the Son are "of a different hypostasis." It took the genius of the [Cappadocian Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappadocian_Fathers) to standardize the terminology so that "the [distinction between *ousia* and *hypostases*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostasis_(philosophy_and_religion)) is the same as that between the general and the particular," and therefore that *hypostasis* would become synonymous with *prosopon*.

Comment: Good document, and very much on point. What language was this letter written in? Presumably Greek? If so, what Greek word is translated "persons"?

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Ugh, I wanted to find a definitive answer to that but couldn't. I too would presume Greek (I'd say the odds are 99.5%), and since it's next to "hypostasis" and given no explanation (in [Schaff's translation](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf214.ix.ix.html) too), I would say _prosopon_ is easily the odds-on favorite.

Comment: Thanks. If you're able to verify that, please let me know.

Comment: Errr, the textual discussion here is beyond me, but [here 'tis with Greek + Latin](http://faculty.cua.edu/pennington/Canon%20Law/Councils/Constantinople%20381.pdf); indeed προσώποις it is (p 28, line 27 of the Greek)! Mr. Bultitude, how did you know that? That’s a very versatile word in *Hebrew* (פנה), but the Greek word in the NT either just means “face” or is used metaphorically, usually in one of the Hebrew senses...but nothing like this AFAIK. There’s obviously more to the later development of this word than I know.... (cc: @LeeWoofenden)

Comment: And now.....[I am officially just wrong](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=92990&context=lsj&action=from-search). :-) Thanks for the education.

Comment: Also, if you can find any on-point documents associated with the earlier council (325), that would be a home run for me!

Comment: @Lee I have edited to add a document from the earlier council. It was the only one I could find.

Comment: The term in Greek that is effectively equivalent to the  Latin _persona_ in Trinitarian theology and Christology is _hypóstasis_ (ὑπόστασις). For instance, where we say "three Person in one Substance," the Greeks would say "three Hypostases in one Ousia." That is the terminology adopted by St. Basil the Great. Prosopon (πρόσωπον, literally “face”) is proposed as an alternative in the text Susan provided, but philosophically _hypostasis_ is closer in meaning to _person_. (_Prosopon_ meant more or less “juridical person” back then; whereas _hypostasis_ meant “individual substance.”)

Comment: As far as documents are concerned, Denzinger is your place to go. Here is an older version (sufficient for this question): https://archive.org/stream/enchiridionsymbo00denz_0#page/8/mode/2up